# javax.persistence.EntityManager source code not found

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I have the problem in my project using spring roo and GWT
When I run the project, this problem in source code appear

No source code is available for type javax.persistence.EntityManager; did you forget to inherit a required module?

I move the jar in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder but this class is not found

Answer (score 2):

That error is caused by the GWT compiler, which needs the source code for all classes being compiled to Javascript.

You probably don't need the `EntityManager` in client side code, so have a look at why the GWT compiler want's that in the first place. Perhaps you need to split your project into logical frontend and backend (and possibly common - for domain etc.) parts.

Cheers,